# SharePoint FBA using AD LDS vs ASNET SQL Membership Database

Tags: 2010, 2013, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have seen many articles describing individual methods of achieving SharePoint  FBA

Using AD LDS [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint__cloud/archive/2011/12/20/achieving-fba-with-adlds-amp-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Using ASPNET SQL Membership database [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg252020%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

And these are not limited and there are many Blogs and articles explaining these.

But my question what are the available methods of achieving FBA and  pros and cons of each method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer at MSDN forums as in the below link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7b261280-b29d-4545-afc0-9c78c05a982b/sharepoint-fba-using-ad-lds-vs-asnet-sql-membership-database?forum=sharepointgeneral